# How to resolve "cannot find symbol method OnClickListener" in Java?

Tags: android

[image: Getting error in my code]

Kindly help me to resolve this error as I'm new in this field and very much eager to know about it.

Comment: For further research by other users, you must have a specific title

Comment: Please get into the habit of (a) using a meaningful title, (b) posting your code and error logs as text not images, (c) describing what you have done to resolve the problem so far. If you would also read the Tour in the Help Centre, that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Its not `button.OnClickListener(Listener)`. It's `button.setOnClickListener(Listener)`

Answer (score 3):

Use `mShowFactButton.setOnClickListener(Listener);` 
And you must follow some standard -

- All reference should be start with small letter(Listener should be listener).
- A function name always start with an small letter.
- On stackoverflow use to copy paste your original code rather than attaching screenshots.

Answer (score 2):

You should use

```
mShowFactButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 // Perform action on click
             }
         });
```